# How do serial queues differ from concurrent queues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm very confused what serial vs concurrent queues are. Does concurrent allow a bunch of operations to be in the queue, and then split them up over available threads, while serial does the same, but limiting it to one thread and waiting for one at a time to finish?

The explanations in the documentation seem very confusing.

Comment: You should read Apple document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"serial" means that the blocks submitted to the queue are executed sequentially,
i.e. the second block is not executed before the first one has finished.
It does *not* mean that the blocks are executed on the same thread.

"concurrent" means that the blocks submitted to the queue *may* execute
concurrently (on different threads).

In both cases, GCD uses a "thread pool" to execute blocks, so you cannot know on which
thread a block will be executed. The only exception is the "main queue" which
executes all blocks on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

[Concurrent (1.)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concurrent) queues:

```
------
------
```

[Serial (6.)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serial) queues:

```
-------
       -------
```

Answer (score 0):

**Queues**: Must be **serial** or **concurrent**. As well as **global** or **private** at the same time.

**Serial queues:**  tasks will be finished one by one
**Concurrent queues:**  tasks will be performed simultaneously and will be finished on unexpected schedules

**Private queues:**  can be both serial or concurrent
**Global queues:**

1. Main Queue : serial
2. Another Queue : concurrent

Queue can be performed synchronously or asynchronously , but this will effect on **parent queue not on queue it self**

So:

- Synchronous function returns control to the parent queue only after
  the task is finished. It blocks the queue and waits until the task is
  finished.
- Asynchronous function returns control to the parent queue right after
  task has been sent to be performed on the different queue. It doesn't
  wait until the task is finished. It doesn't block the parent queue.